# Django save changes not reflecting on database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know there are some similar posts, but nothing I've read could fix my issue. I have the following model:

```py
class Run(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    script = models.ForeignKey(Script, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parameters = models.ForeignKey(Parameters, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weights = models.ForeignKey(Weights, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    train_score = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    validation_score = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and the following function:

```py
def save_run(run_id: str, model, train_score: float, validation_score: float):
    ...
    run: Run = Run.objects.get(id=run_id)
    run.train_score = train_score
    run.validation_score = validation_score
    run.save()
```

but, even though it finds the run on the database, "saves successfully" and logs all attributes fine, even after saving it, the changes don't reflect on the database. I've tried forcing with `update_fields=["train_score", "validation_score"]` and `force_update=True` without success. Any ideas?

Comment: can you add more context where from/how you call `save_run()`? Isnt there any follow-up code doing another `save()` and thus overwriting back the data?

Comment: Is this the only model called `Run` in your installed apps? Do you happen to have an unhandled exception later on in the request-response cycle that maybe causes the transaction to be rolled back? 
Maybe a race condition where another request retetrieves the unchanged object and saves it? Or is there another Run object around somewhere representing the same run that also gets saved?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko there is indeed a shared `Run` object that would then overwrite the data. The moment I've read your comment I realized that. If you want to write a formal answer, I'll pick yours as the correct one. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm good. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    run: Run = Run.objects.get(id=run_id)
    run.train_score = train_score
    run.validation_score = validation_score
    run.save()
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```